# how to get dataframe cell content from another cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

| image | labels |
| --- | --- |
| image1 | now |
| image2 | yesterday |

I need the value in the column '*labels*' that I get from this loop

```
for image in os.listdir('train_images'):
   if df_train['image'].str.contains(image).any():
       print('labels')
```

I get image1 here and I want the value in the column labels

The final result has to be like this:

|  |
| --- |
| now |
| yesterday |

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['image1', 'now'], ['image2', 'yesterday']]),
                   columns=['image', 'labels'])
```

The solution can be simple - if only 2 columns: (resultType: Dataframe)

```
del df['image']
df
```

[image]

But if there x column then: (resultType: object)

```
onlyLabels = df['labels']
onlyLabels
```

[image]

(resultType: strings)

```
for i in df['labels']: 
    print (i)
```

[image]

---